# Node.js and protocol buffers - I have a <SlowBuffer >? What is that?

Tags: node.js, protocol-buffers

I am struggling understanding protocol buffers in node.js...

I receive a message from a post.  I

```
var Schema = require('protobuf').Schema;
var schema = new Schema(fs.readFileSync('/home/ubuntu/workspace/MySchmae.desc'));

var Feed  = schema['MySchema'];
var serialized = Feed.serialize(req.body);
```

The value of serialized is a .  I am assuming that this my object I want to parse.  There is a field called country.  I tried serialized.country but I get undefined.

As a side..are the any good tutorials other than the non descript one pager form proto node?

Comment: Don't use SlowBuffer!! See docs: http://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_class_slowbuffer

If the protobuf uses SlowBuffers change to another module!

Comment: I have no choice...I have no accept protocol buffers. I dont even know if I am doing the right thing with p buffers per the question.

Comment: The "serialize" method accepts an object and returns a Buffer. What are you trying to do?